# How do you breed a Dodo dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

What dragon combinations can I used to breed this dragon? Which dragons should I breed and how will I know whether I got one? How long are they available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Dodo Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Dodo_Dragon) can be bred by pairing an earth dragon with an air hybrid.  For example: 
an Earth dragon and a Chrome dragon is reported to work.  You'll know you have a Dodo Dragon if you get a breeding time of 16 hours. The egg is brown with a wind symbol on it.

Dodo dragons are a hidden dragon that started appearing April 13th.  The description suggests that they may be in the marketplace soon, possibly with other new dragons.

> Cave drawings of the dodo dragon were first discovered on Mooretoss Island long ago by the great explorer Lewis Dodoson. They depict an ancient, flightless, and rather clumsy dragon. For centuries it was thought to be extinct, but we now know that while the dodo dragon may be rare, it is certainly not extinct! I wonder what other dragons have yet to be discovered!

It is not clear at this time if this will be a limited time dragon.

Here is a video showing the successful Earth+Chrome combination:

Comment: It's extremely doubtful it's a limited time dragon, those are always announced, this is just one of the "opposites" dragons like Sandstorm, bluefire ect. The Frostfire dragon was hidden just like this when it was released as well

Comment: I can confirm that I've got my first on the way with Earth + Chrome.  It was by no means easy - probably about 5 attempts, but I eventually got one.  Good luck to those still trying... :)

Answer (score -1):

Earth & chrome 
Or earth and other air hybrid

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please try and answer questions with more than just a one-liner, or at the very least a fully formed sentence. :)

Answer (score -3):

You need to breed a Willow with an Earth.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please try and answer questions with more than just a one-liner, or at the very least a fully formed sentence. :)

Answer (score -3):

Breed a sandstorm and an earth

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please try and answer questions with more than just a one-liner, or at the very least a fully formed sentence. :)